# "&" Character in XML Displaying in AMPscript/Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml, triggered-send

I have a Triggered Send erroring because of the `&` character being used in values.

I have an XML column in one of my Data Extensions. I have some values that contain the `&` character. For example, `<item>Blue & Red Cups</item>`.

Is there anything I can do in the AMPscript within the email to convert them to `&amp;`? Or would it actually need to be `&amp;` in the XML?

---

Based on your comments below, any direction on how I would apply CDATA to the ITEMPRODUCTNAME variable?

```
%%[ 

var @XML, @rowCount
SET @XML = AttributeValue("XML") 
SET @productRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@XML, "/root/ITEM", 0) ]%% 

%%[ 

for @j = 1 to RowCount(@productRows) do 

    SET @productXML = Concat("", Field(Row(@productRows, @j), "XML"), "") 
    SET @ITEMPRODUCTNAME = Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME", 0), 1), "Value")) 

]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

1. You can include the HTML entity (`&amp;`) inside of your XML instead of the `&`. `&` is a restricted character in XML and cannot be used on its own. See referenced answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500800/how-can-i-include-an-ampersand-character-in-an-xml-document)
2. You can place a rare to never used char inside of the XML and then use a [Replace()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm) function inside AMPscript to turn it into an ampersand (&).  For example: `@myAttr = "Blue ~ Red Cups"` and then do `Replace(@myAttr, "~", "&")` to return the `~` to `&` in the AMPscript var. Output: `"Blue & Red Cups"`.
3. A combination of both. If you would rather have the symbol itself inside the output, but don't want to chance using another symbol or character being overwritten, you can combine these two.  Using `&amp;` inside your XML and then using the Replace() function on it in AMPScript.  like so: `Replace(@myAttr, "&amp;", "&")`.

My personal recommendation would be option one, replacing the `&` with the HTML entity. This removes any server side processing and allows the XML call to be used universally and not limited to just SFMC.

---

**EDIT**
Samples of Replace() solution:

Using CDATA:

```
SET @XML = AttributeValue("XML")

SET @XML = REPLACE(@xml, '<ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME>', '<ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME><![CDATA[')
/* First Replace to add in the 'prefix' of CDATA into the XML */

SET @XML = REPLACE(@xml, '</ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME>', ']]></ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME>')
/* Second Replace to add in the 'suffix' or closing of the CDATA into the XML

SET @productRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@ XML, "/root/ITEM", 0) ]%%
```

The rest of your code to parse out the info should be able to remain the same. Now please note that the above is 'theory' and not definitive, I have not tested this to ensure it works. So there may be some kinks here or there.

Using a different char:

```
SET @XML = AttributeValue("XML")

SET @XML = REPLACE(@xml, ' & ', ' ~ ')
/* Replace *space*&*space* with *space*~*space* inside XML */

SET @productRows = BuildRowSetFromXML(@ XML, "/root/ITEM", 0) ]%%

SET @ productXML = Concat("", Field(Row(@ productRows, @ j), "XML"), "")

SET @ ITEMPRODUCTNAME = Replace(Trim(Field(Row(BuildRowSetFromXML(@ productXML, "ITEM/ITEM_PRODUCT_NAME", 0), 1), "Value")), " ~ ", " & ")
/* Returns the character from ~ to & after pulled from XML. */
```

This does open up to the possibility of accidentally replacing a char that was not meant to be replaced, but usually this margin of error is insignificant.